# How to template a variable in a javascript file with webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

In a project structured with Webpack 4, one of my javascript sources looks like

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename='/tmsb/dist'>
      <Application />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

I would like to insert into `basename` some value depending on some *build condition* (pro/dev).

I can use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to do that in my `index.html`, but what about a javascript file?

Should I add a new `HtmlWebpackPlugin` entry for this specific javascript file, or is there another preferred way?

It seems that this is not job for `HtmlWebpackPlugin` since this javascript file should remain in `src/` and not copied to some `build` folder.

Maybe I could use the html5 `<base>` element for  that (any query its value from javascript)?

Comment: [This might help](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5)

Comment: It did help. And it was funny to read people's reaction on bag of deecks :P

Comment: Huh. I missed that. It really lowers the tone of what's generally a good article.

Comment: Although funny, indeed it does.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to pass variables into react javascript using the webpack DefinePlugin

```js
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(devMode()),
          'BASENAME': JSON.stringify(baseName())
        }
      }),
```

which allows in javascript to reference 'baseName' as

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.BASENAME}>
      <Application />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Instead of `JSON.stringify` someone may just write `'"myvalue"'` instead of `JSON.stringify('myvalue')`.